# comparación de objetos anidados dentro de un objeto para generar otro objeto

Tags: javascript, angular7, objeto, javascript-objeto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Me encuentro atascado en un problema que no se como abordar. Estoy realizando unas pruebas en angular y me encuentro en un punto de la aplicación en el que recibo un objeto con objetos anidados:

```
{
  0: {
    x: 200,
    y: 350,
    propiedades: {
      id: 1,
      nombre: A,
      entradas: {
        entrada_0: { id: 1, cajaId: 1, color: azul },
        entrada_1: { id: 2, cajaId: 1, color: rojo },
      },
      salidas: {
        salida_0: { id: 1, cajaId: 1, color: azul },
        salida_1: { id: 2, cajaId: 1, color: rojo },
      },
    },
  },
  1: {
    x: 600,
    y: 550,
    propiedades: {
      id: 2,
      nombre: B,
      entradas: {
        entrada_0: { id: 1, cajaId: 2, color: azul },
        entrada_1: { id: 2, cajaId: 2, color: rojo },
      },
      salidas: { salida_0: { id: 1, cajaId: 2, color: verde } },
    },
  },
  2: {
    x: 100,
    y: 450,
    propiedades: {
      id: 3,
      nombre: C,
      entradas: {
        entrada_0: { id: 1, cajaId: 3, color: azul },
        entrada_1: { id: 2, cajaId: 3, color: verde },
      },
      salidas: {
        salida_0: { id: 1, cajaId: 3, color: azul },
        salida_1: { id: 2, cajaId: 3, color: rojo },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

necesito

1. recorrer uno a uno los objetos,
2. chequear que color de las salidas del objeto actual coincide con el color de las entradas del los siguientes
   y
3. generar un objeto que indique todas las posibles uniones, generando un objeto que en este caso sería:

```
{
  0: {
    desdeCaja: '0',
    desdeSalida: 'salida_0',
    aCaja: '1',
    aEntrada: 'entrada_0',
  },
  1: {
    desdeCaja: '0',
    desdeSalida: 'salida_1',
    aCaja: '1',
    aEntrada: 'entrada_1',
  },
  2: {
    desdeCaja: '1',
    desdeSalida: 'salida_0',
    aCaja: '2',
    aEntrada: 'entrada_1',
  },
}
```

He probado a obtener el valor de las cajas utilizando el Object.values de las cajas dentro del objeto pero cuando empiezo a recorrerlas en un bucle ya no se como continuar a guardar datos para terminar metiendolos el objetos final...

```
const cajas = Object.values(data.cajas);
for (const caja of cajas) {
 console.log(caja , "obteniendo un objeto por cada caja incluida en el objeto original")
}
```

Si alguien me puede echar un mano se agradece.
Gracias por adelantado y buen dia.

Comment: 1. Qué objetos, a qué nivel de profundidad? 
2. 0.propiedades.salidas.salida_[0,1,...].color === propiedades.entradas.entrada_[0,1,...].color ?
3. Puedes poner un ejemplo completo de la respuesta final que esperas?

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia el objeto que recibo y quiero recorrer es el primer bloque de codigo y la respuesta que espero se corresponde con el segundo bloque de codigo, que serian un objeto creado a partir de los datos obtenidos del objeto original

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia la intención es crear unas conexiones entre cajas teniendo en cuenta el color de las salidas de una caja que coincida con el color de las entradas de la siguientes

Comment: Podrías especificar los criterios para formar este objecto? 0: {
    desdeCaja: '0',
    desdeSalida: 'salida_0',
    aCaja: '1',
    aEntrada: 'entrada_0',
  },

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia estoy utilizando un libreria que forma este objeto al generar los conectores entre las cajas y lo que deseo es implementar un boton en la aplicacion con el que autoconectar las mismas sin necesidad de ir arrastrando de uno a otro y contemplando todas las posibles conexiones existentes

Comment: Si, eso lo he entendido, pero para poder ayudarte, necesito saber los criterios exactos para formar el objeto, si los puedes detallar verbalmente, podré entender las condiciones para formar el objeto final sino, con dudas no puedo.

Comment: necesito recorrer el primer objeto, en el que vienen todas las cajas con sus propiedas, empezando por el primero, en el que tendria que buscar el color de la primera salida y chequear si alguna de las entradas de las siguientes cajas coinciden en valor, de ser asi, necesito guardar el numero de la caja origen ("0") junto con el valor de su salida coincidente ("salida_0"), y el numero de la caja receptora ("1") y su entrada con mismo color ("entrada_0").

Comment: entiendo que necesitaria hacer un bucle dentro de otro pero por mas que intento no veo la manera de ir chequeando los datos coincidentes en color y extrayendolo a un nuevo objeto @AdolfoOnrubia espero haberte aclarado algo, muchas gracias por el interes

Comment: Creo que lo he entendido ahora, te ayudo en cuanto saque unos minutos ;), cuenta con ello

Comment: muchisimas gracias @AdolfoOnrubia, he añadido un pequeño esquema en una imagen por si se entiende mejor

Comment: he empezado pero no terminado, la parte de salidas_0, 1, que no esté controlada desconcierta un poco así que cuando termine de trabajar le echo otro ratito y te digo ;)

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia me ha surgido una duda que quizas me sepas aclarar, veo que el "id" por el que identificamos las mismas no es secuencial y llega un punto en el que falla la lógica. Habría forma de utilizar las keys del array que generamos al hacer el forEach? veo que en ese caso, incluso al eliminar cajas o que el valor no sea secuencial, al querer volver a conectar siempre se cumple el orden correcto para la creacion de las conexiones. Muchas gracias por adelantado y disculpa las molestias

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia me refiero al indice que se les asigna a cada caja dentro del objeto genera, ya que en caso de eliminar alguna de las cajas ese numero se reasigna y sigue un orden logico... {cajas: 0:{...}, 1:{...}, 2:{....}}.... el indice de cada caja

Comment: Y no podrías basarte en los items de la lista que son los que tienen conexiones para hacer los match en base a los ids en vez de alos indices?

Comment: buenas idea... muchas gracias @AdolfoOnrubia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que veo devolviendo un objeto es que machacas las posibles combinaciones quedandote con la última.
Una manera de atajar eso es la segunda opción que te propongo que devulve una lista de todas las combinaciones posibles.
Y bueno, pues parece que al final ha sido posible, te dejo la respuesta para que la evalues:

```js
const data = {
  0: {
    x: 200,
    y: 350,
    propiedades: {
      id: 1,
      nombre: "A",
      entradas: {
        entrada_0: { id: 1, cajaId: 1, color: "azul" },
        entrada_1: { id: 2, cajaId: 1, color: "rojo" },
      },
      salidas: {
        salida_0: { id: 1, cajaId: 1, color: "azul" },
        salida_1: { id: 2, cajaId: 1, color: "rojo" },
      },
    },
  },
  1: {
    x: 600,
    y: 550,
    propiedades: {
      id: 2,
      nombre: "B",
      entradas: {
        entrada_0: { id: 1, cajaId: 2, color: "azul" },
        entrada_1: { id: 2, cajaId: 2, color: "rojo" },
      },
      salidas: { salida_0: { id: 1, cajaId: 2, color: "verde" } },
    },
  },
  2: {
    x: 100,
    y: 450,
    propiedades: {
      id: 3,
      nombre: "C",
      entradas: {
        entrada_0: { id: 1, cajaId: 3, color: "azul" },
        entrada_1: { id: 2, cajaId: 3, color: "verde" },
      },
      salidas: {
        salida_0: { id: 1, cajaId: 3, color: "azul" },
        salida_1: { id: 2, cajaId: 3, color: "rojo" },
      },
    },
  },
}
const _values = Object.values(data);

const res = {};
_values.forEach((next, index, box) => {
  const others = box.filter(b => b.propiedades.id !== next.propiedades.id)
  const entradasKeys = Object.keys(next.propiedades.entradas);
  const entradasValues = Object.values(next.propiedades.entradas);

  entradasKeys.forEach((entrada, eIndex) => {
    others.forEach((caja) => {
      const salidasKeys = Object.keys(caja.propiedades.salidas);
      const salidasValues = Object.values(caja.propiedades.salidas);
      salidasValues.forEach((salida, sIndex) => {
        if (salida.color === entradasValues[eIndex].color) {
          res[index] = {
            desdeCaja: caja.propiedades.id - 1,
            desdeSalida: salidasKeys[sIndex],
            aCaja: next.propiedades.id - 1,
            aEntrada: entrada
          }
        }
      })
    })
  })
});

console.log(res)
```

Aunque si lo que esperas encontrar es una relación de todas las posibilidades sería lo siguiente:

```js
const data = {
  0: {
    x: 200,
    y: 350,
    propiedades: {
      id: 1,
      nombre: "A",
      entradas: {
        entrada_0: { id: 1, cajaId: 1, color: "azul" },
        entrada_1: { id: 2, cajaId: 1, color: "rojo" },
      },
      salidas: {
        salida_0: { id: 1, cajaId: 1, color: "azul" },
        salida_1: { id: 2, cajaId: 1, color: "rojo" },
      },
    },
  },
  1: {
    x: 600,
    y: 550,
    propiedades: {
      id: 2,
      nombre: "B",
      entradas: {
        entrada_0: { id: 1, cajaId: 2, color: "azul" },
        entrada_1: { id: 2, cajaId: 2, color: "rojo" },
      },
      salidas: { salida_0: { id: 1, cajaId: 2, color: "verde" } },
    },
  },
  2: {
    x: 100,
    y: 450,
    propiedades: {
      id: 3,
      nombre: "C",
      entradas: {
        entrada_0: { id: 1, cajaId: 3, color: "azul" },
        entrada_1: { id: 2, cajaId: 3, color: "verde" },
      },
      salidas: {
        salida_0: { id: 1, cajaId: 3, color: "azul" },
        salida_1: { id: 2, cajaId: 3, color: "rojo" },
      },
    },
  },
}
const _values = Object.values(data);

const res = [];
_values.forEach((next, index, box) => {
  const others = box.filter(b => b.propiedades.id !== next.propiedades.id)
  const entradasKeys = Object.keys(next.propiedades.entradas);
  const entradasValues = Object.values(next.propiedades.entradas);

  entradasKeys.forEach((entrada, eIndex) => {
    others.forEach((caja) => {
      const salidasKeys = Object.keys(caja.propiedades.salidas);
      const salidasValues = Object.values(caja.propiedades.salidas);
      salidasValues.forEach((salida, sIndex) => {
        if (salida.color === entradasValues[eIndex].color) {
          res.push({
            [index]: {
              desdeCaja: caja.propiedades.id - 1,
              desdeSalida: salidasKeys[sIndex],
              aCaja: next.propiedades.id - 1,
              aEntrada: entrada
            }
          })
        }
      })
    })
  })
});


console.log('res', res)
```

Comment: cualquiera de la dos opciones funciona perfectamente, pero com obien dices es mucho mas completa la segunda, que contempla todas las posibles conexiones. Muchisimas gracias por tu tiempo y tu ayuda!!

Comment: me ha surgido una duda que quizas me sepas aclarar, veo que el id por el que identificamos las mismas no es secuencial y llega un punto en el que falla la lógica. Habría forma de utilizar las keys del array que generamos al hacer el forEach? entiendo que en ese caso, incluso en el supuesto de eliminar cajas o que el valor no sea secuencial, al querer volver a conectar siempre se cumple el orden correcto para la creacion de las conexiones

Comment: No termino de comprender a lo que te refieres, es posible que sea por el `[index]`??

Answer (score 1):

Porque no usas Reduce?

*arr.reduce(callback(acumulador, valorActual[, índice[, array]])[, valorInicial])*

sin acabar de programarte el ejercicio seria algo así:

```
const retorno = cajas.reduce((acumula, elemento, indice, boxes) => {
  const color = elemento.propiedades.salidas.color;
  console.log(color);
  // no acabo de entender la salida pero ...
  const nuevoArr = {
     desdeSalida: Object.keys(elemento.propiedades.salidas).some(key => key.includes('salida_')), // extraemos la clave 
     desdeEntrada: Object.keys(elemento.propiedades.entradas).some(key => key.includes('entrada_')), // extraemos la clave
     caja: isset(boxes[indice+1]) ? boxes[indice+1].propiedades.entradas[0].cajaId : 0, // accedemos al elemento siguiente del array
  }

  return acumulador.push(nuevoArr);
}
```

El código no funcionara porque no lo he probado ni depurado, pero te dará una idea de lo que debes hacer.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, lo pruebo y te digo! @Mork

Comment: Si, pruebalo y lo vamos depurando.